# Creating events with google closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure

I would like to use events to communicate between my objects in a google closure (GC) environment.

Suppose I have two classes `foobar.Boss` and `foobar.Employee`. The Boss wants to know when the Employee has made coffee, and whether or not that coffee is decaf (he's laying off the caffeine this week).

GC has made classes available that seem to provide the means to do this, `goog.events.Event` and `goog.events.EventTarget`.

Without knowing better, I'd think it would work like this:

```
foobar.Employee.prototype.makeCoffee = function(isDecaf)
{        
    this.coffeeMaker.putCoffeeInMachine(isDecaf);
    this.coffeeMaker.start();
    var event = new goog.event.Event('COFFEE_ON', { isDecaf: isDecaf });
    goog.events.dispatchEvent(event);
}

foobar.Boss.prototype.addEmployee = function(employee)
{
    ...
    goog.events.listen(employee, 'COFFEE_ON', function(e)
    {
        if (e.target.isDecaf)
        {
            this.refillMug();
        }
    }, false, this);
    ...
}
```

Is this a correct pattern? I am confused by the class `goog.events.EventTarget` -- how does a target dispatch events? Doesn't a target have things happen to it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411840/problems-creating-custom-event-dispatcher-in-google-closure-library) is helpful, but a more direct answer would be appreciated.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/fx/fx.js?r=2#582 Is an example implementation -- inheriting from goog.events.EventTarget seems strange (is it completely necessary that Employee extends EventTarget?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having looked at this for a while, my understanding is now that the `EventTarget` in fact plays a dual roll of being the entity that dispatches events and the entity that is listened to. So one option would be to have `Employee` inherit `goog.events.EventTarget` but I have gone a different route.

First I created a new event type that would let the Boss know if the coffee was decaf.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.events.Event}
 */
foobar.CoffeeEvent = function(isDecaf)
{
  goog.events.Event.call(this, 'COFFEE_ON');
  this.isDecaf = isDecaf;
};
goog.inherits(foobar.CoffeeEvent, goog.events.Event);
```

Next I created an event listener type to dispatch these events.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @extends {goog.events.EventTarget} 
 */
foobar.CoffeeEventTarget = function()
{
  goog.events.EventTarget.call(this);
};
goog.inherits(foobar.CoffeeEventTarget, goog.events.EventTarget);
```

I added an object of this type to my `Employee`.

```
foobar.Employee = function()
{
  ...
  this.coffeeEvents = new foobar.CoffeeEventTarget();
  ...
}
```

When the employee refills the coffee:

```
foobar.Employee.prototype.makeCoffee = function(isDecaf)
{        
    this.coffeeMaker.putCoffeeInMachine(isDecaf);
    this.coffeeMaker.start();
    var event = new foobar.CoffeeEvent(isDecaf);
    this.coffeeEvents.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Mr. Bossman listens for this.

```
foobar.Boss.prototype.addEmployee = function(employee)
{
    ...
    goog.events.listen(employee.coffeeEvents, 'COFFEE_ON', function(e)
    {
        if (e.isDecaf)
        {
            this.refillMug();
        }
    }, false, this);
    ...
}
```

Note that this won't tell me *which* employee refilled the coffee, because the event target will an instance of `CoffeeEventTarget`. If you wanted all of `Employee` in there I suppose you could add it as a member field. If you were OK with inheriting to `Employee` from `goog.events.EventTarget` then you get `Employee` for free as the target.

Comment: foobar.CoffeeEvent should probably accept a type, rather than having it hardcoded. This would be a good use for an enum.

Comment: Still looking at this. There is probably no real need in my case to subclass EventTarget.

Answer (score 1):

The way I think of EventTarget is this:

A **button** is a target, which you can register to be notified about its click event whenever one takes place. Thus, the "target" of a click is the button (you aim at the button, then click on it). But when the button gets clicked, it's not the mouse that tells everyone that the button was clicked - the button itself dispatches that message.

To touch on the question brought up by @ben-flynn about *why would someone need/want to subclass EventTarget*:

If you want to listen for **key down** events, you probably care about what key was pressed. The way you'd know what key was pressed is by looking up the keyCode field on the **event** object that is dispatched by the KeyDownEventTarget. On the other hand, a ButtonEventTarget dispatches a different event object, namely a ClickEvent, which does not have a keyCode field in it. So to summarize, the reason you'd subclass EventTarget is so whoever is listening for events that will be dispatched by that target know what event object will be dispatched when the event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it...

Let's set up a coffee type. If we were to take this further we could have a base Coffee class and then sub class it with a DecafCoffee class. But lets keep things simple.

**foobar.Coffee.js**

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Coffee class
 */

goog.provide('foobar.Coffee');

/**
 * @constructor
 */
foobar.Coffee = function(){
   //...
};
```

Our Employee class must implement *goog.events.EventTarget* to be able to dispatch events. You mustn't forget to call the parent constructor with `goog.base` or `goog.events.EventTarget.call` either as this will setup internal variables the class needs.

**foobar.Employee.js**

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Implements the Employee class
 */

goog.provide('foobar.Employee');
goog.require('goog.events.EventTarget');
goog.require('foobar.Coffee');

/**
 * @constructor
 */
foobar.Employee = function(){
    // Calls the parent class (goog.events.EventTarget)
    goog.base(this);
};
goog.inherits(foobar.Employee, goog.events.EventTarget);

/**
 * Make a coffee
 */
foobar.Employee.prototype.makeCoffee = function(){
    // Determine what coffee type to make ...
    // Create the coffee
    var coffee = new foobar.Coffee();
    this.dispatchEvent({
        type: "decaf_coffee",
        target: coffee
    });
};
```

The boss class doesn't need to do anything special as it won't be dispatching events. It just needs a `#drinkCoffee()` method we can call.

**foobar.Boss.js**

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Implements the Boss class
 */

goog.provide('foobar.Boss');

/**
 * @constructor
 */
foobar.Boss = function(){
   //...
};

/**
 * Make this boss drink coffee
 * @param {foobar.Coffee} coffee The coffee to drink
 */
foobar.Boss.prototype.drinkCoffee = function(coffee){
    //....
};
```

This is the main JavaScript code which you'll be running, you can put wherever you like, e.g. inline in the browser or in its own script.

**main.js**

```
goog.require('foobar.Boss');
goog.require('foobar.Employee');
goog.require('goog.events');

// Jane is the boss of Sam, but we will use lower case as I typically 
// only capitalise the first letter to indicate a constructor.
var jane = new Boss();
var sam = new Employee();

// Set up event listening
goog.events.listen(sam, "decaf_coffee", function(e){
    var coffee = e.target;
    // We've got the decaf coffee Sam made, now Jane can enjoy drinking it
    jane.drinkCoffee(coffee);
}, false, this);

// Tell Sam to make a coffee
sam.makeCoffee();
```